# Conversion of DateTime to relative time

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The following code does not seem to work correctly when comparing DateTimes under certain circumstances.

For example, when the comparison DateTime is less than 24 hours, the function will return the incorrect minutes. Is there a better way to approach this?

```
Public Function GetElapsedTimeAsString(givenDate As DateTime) As String
    Return ConvertTimeSpanToTotalAgo(DateTime.Now.Subtract(givenDate))
End Function

Private Shared Function ConvertTimeSpanToTotalAgo(diffDate As TimeSpan) As String
    Dim d As New StringBuilder()
    If diffDate.Days > 0 Then
        d.AppendFormat("{0} Day ago ", diffDate.Days)
    ElseIf diffDate.Minutes > 0 Then
        d.AppendFormat("{0} Minutes ago ", diffDate.Minutes)
    ElseIf diffDate.Seconds > 0 Then
        d.AppendFormat("{0} Seconds ago ", diffDate.Seconds)
    ElseIf diffDate.Milliseconds > 0 Then
        d.AppendFormat("Just Now", diffDate.Milliseconds)
    End If
    Return d.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: Define "does not seem to work correctly" and "certain circumstances".  How does it fail?

Comment: Does *it doesn't display the number of hours* count as a problem? Because it doesn't. ;)

Comment: Your function will only display "1 Day ago" if there is a 1 Day, 5 Hour, 43 minute, 30 second time difference.  See my GetElapsedTimeDescription below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of days, minutes, seconds and milliseconds is zero, and the number of hours is nonzero, it'll report nothing, i.e. an empty string. You need to add

```
    If diffDate.Hours > 0 Then
        d.AppendFormat("{0} Hours ago ", diffDate.Hours
```

at the very least.

Maybe deal with pluralisation as well: you're mixing plural and singular, e.g.

```
    If diffDate.Hours > 0 Then
        Dim text = If (diffDate.Hours > 1, "Hours", "Hour")
        d.AppendFormat("{0} {1} ago ", diffDate.Hours,text
```

Apologies if this doesn't build - I'm from a C# background, and was looking for a VB.NET equivalent to the [ternary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) operator.

Comment: That did it. What would be the most efficient way of dealing with pluralization?

Comment: How's that? As I say, I'm not 100% about the syntax, but that's how I think it'd work.

Answer (score 0):

The following function will properly display the elapsed Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds, and optionally Milliseconds between two DateTimes.

```
MessageBox.Show("Completed in " & GetElapedTimeDescription(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(5).AddHours(1).AddMinutes(3).AddSeconds(1)) & ".")
```

displays: "Completed in 5 Days, 1 Hour, 3 Minutes, 1 Second."

```
Private Shared Function GetElapedTimeDescription(ByVal startTime As DateTime, ByVal endTime As DateTime, Optional ByVal includeMilliseconds As Boolean = False) As String
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = endTime - startTime
    Dim elapsed As New System.Text.StringBuilder(100)

    If startTime > endTime Then
        ts = startTime - endTime
    End If

    If ts.Days > 0 Then
        elapsed.AppendFormat("{0} Day{1}, ", ts.Days, If(ts.Days > 1, "s", ""))
    End If
    If ts.Hours > 0 Then
        elapsed.AppendFormat("{0} Hour{1}, ", ts.Hours, If(ts.Hours > 1, "s", ""))
    End If
    If ts.Minutes > 0 Then
        elapsed.AppendFormat("{0} Minute{1}, ", ts.Minutes, If(ts.Minutes > 1, "s", ""))
    End If
    If ts.Seconds > 0 Then
        elapsed.AppendFormat("{0} Second{1}, ", ts.Seconds, If(ts.Seconds > 1, "s", ""))
    End If

    If includeMilliseconds Then
        If ts.Milliseconds > 0 Then
            elapsed.AppendFormat("{0} Millisecond{1}, ", ts.Milliseconds, If(ts.Milliseconds > 1, "s", ""))
        End If
    End If

    If elapsed.ToString() = "" Then
        elapsed.Append("Less than 1 Second")
    End If

    If elapsed.ToString().EndsWith(", ") Then
        elapsed.Remove(elapsed.Length - 2, 2)
    End If

    Return elapsed.ToString()
End Function
```